# MEAN app with angular 2 error: Cannot read property _id of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am building an application for the first time to store, update, view and delete Client profiles. I followed the Angular tour of heroes to build the basic app and then pieced together the mongodb and express portions from around the net.

I am getting this error in my browser console when i attempt to delete a client profile -

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
>       at ClientProfileComp.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/components/clientProfile.component.ts.ClientProfileComp.delete
>   (clientProfile.component.ts:53)... (etc).

I have confirmed using postman that my express routing is working as intended. I am able to get all/create clients at `/api/clients`, as well as get, put and delete from `/api/clients/:_id` (where _id is the autogenerated id for each entry).

I believe the problem is in one of my component files, as the error only occurs when I attempt to delete or view specific client detail, which causes another type of error entirely (CastError). The problem likely began when I attempted to remove all mentions of `clientProfile: ClientProfile[];` (or Hero in the case of the tutorial) as I am no longer importing the details from `client.ts` (hero.ts) since I am using a mongoose schema instead, and I do not believe I should be importing that schema into my front-end angular.

here is the delete section of clientProfile.service.ts:

```
delete(_id: number): Promise<void>  {
    const url = `${this.clientProfilesUrl}/${_id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers}).toPromise()
    .then(() => null).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and here is clientProfile.component.ts as requested (the most likely source of my problem being that i replaced all instances of `clientProfile: ClientProfile;` with `clientProfile: any;` without knowing what I was doing)
note the commented out import statement.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

//import { ClientProfile } from '../old/clientProfile';
import { ClientProfileService } from '../services/clientProfile.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-clientprofile',
templateUrl: '../views/clientProfile.component.html',
styleUrls: [ '../styles/clientprofile.component.css' ]
})

export class ClientProfileComp implements OnInit {
selectedClientProfile: any;
clientProfiles: any = [];
clientProfile: any;

constructor(
    private clientProfileService: ClientProfileService,
    private router: Router
) { }

gotoDetail(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedClientProfile._id]);
}

getClientProfiles(): void {
    this.clientProfileService.getClientProfiles().then(clientProfiles => {
        this.clientProfiles = clientProfiles;
    });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getClientProfiles();
}

onSelect(clientProfile: any): void {
    this.selectedClientProfile = clientProfile;
}

add(name: string, address: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    address = address.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.clientProfileService.create(name, address).then(clientProfile => {
        this.clientProfiles.push(clientProfile);
            this.selectedClientProfile = null;
    this.getClientProfiles();
    });
}

delete(clientProfile: any): void {
    this.clientProfileService.delete(clientProfile._id).then(() => {
        this.clientProfiles = this.clientProfiles.filter(h => h !== 
clientProfile);
        if (this.selectedClientProfile === clientProfile) { this.selectedClientProfile = null; }
    });
}
}
```

I have been poring over this all day, and have read a lot of similar posts here too - but most of the solutions don't seem to apply to this case. If anyone could point me in the right direction, i'd be really grateful. if any more code is needed to explain what i'm trying to do i will gladly post it.

Comment: Error it self says that its not finding `_id` on undefind field which means in your `clientProfile.component.ts` when you are doing `clientProfile._id` at that time `clientProfile` is `undefined`

Comment: post full code of your`clientProfile.component.ts`

Comment: is above code from (clientProfile.component.ts:53) ?

Comment: @TarangRathod correct.

Comment: @ranakrunal9 i will edit the post to include the full code of that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out one problem - my delete button in the html file was in a div that only appeared when a client was selected, instead of next to each client. this was a result of a half-finished measure i took to ensure users don't just click delete willy-nilly on each client.

Code before:

```
<h2>Client Profiles</h2>
<div class="add-client">
<label>Add new client</label>
<input placeholder="Client Name (required)" #clientProfileName />
<input placeholder="Client Address" #clientProfileAddress />
<button (click)="add(clientProfileName.value, clientProfileAddress.value); 
clientProfileName.value=''; clientProfileAddress.value=''">
    Add</button>
</div>
<ul class="clientProfiles">
<li *ngFor="let clientProfile of clientProfiles"
    [class.selected]="clientProfile === selectedClientProfile"
    (click)="onSelect(clientProfile)">
    <span class="badge">{{clientProfile.idnumber}}</span>
    <span>{{clientProfile.name}}</span>
</li>
</ul>
<div *ngIf="selectedClientProfile">
<h2>
    {{selectedClientProfile.name | uppercase}} selected
</h2>
<button (click)="gotoDetail()">View Details</button>
<button class="delete"
        (click)="delete(clientProfile); 
$event.stopPropagation()">Delete</button>
//delete button will only appear when a client is selected
</div>
```

Code now:

```
<h2>Client Profiles</h2>
<div class="add-client">
<label>Add new client</label>
<input placeholder="Client Name (required)" #clientProfileName />
<input placeholder="Client Address" #clientProfileAddress />
<button (click)="add(clientProfileName.value, clientProfileAddress.value); 
clientProfileName.value=''; clientProfileAddress.value=''">
    Add</button>
</div>
<ul class="clientProfiles">
<li *ngFor="let clientProfile of clientProfiles"
    [class.selected]="clientProfile === selectedClientProfile"
    (click)="onSelect(clientProfile)">
    <span class="badge">{{clientProfile.idnumber}}</span>
    <span>{{clientProfile.name}}</span>
    <button class="delete"
        (click)="delete(clientProfile); 
$event.stopPropagation()">Delete</button>
//delete button appears next to each client
</li>
</ul>
<div *ngIf="selectedClientProfile">
<h2>
    {{selectedClientProfile.name | uppercase}} selected
</h2>
<button (click)="gotoDetail()">View Details</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message it seems that the error is here:

```
this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedClientProfile._id])
```

It appears that you only set it in `onSelect` and there are several places in your code that you are setting `this.selectedClientProfile` to null. That would be the best place to look.

If you'd like to create a plunker that demonstrates your issue, we could look at it further.

As a side note, you are using promises instead of the now more common Observables. If you want to change over to using Observables, I have a complete example of CRUD (create, read, update, and delete) operations here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms in the APM folder.

Comment: thank you, I've had a few observable/promise related errors during dev, i will give your link a look.

Comment: This may be an even better resource as it shows the Angular with Mongo and Express: https://www.sitepoint.com/mean-stack-angular-2-angular-cli/

Comment: When i activate gotoDetail, the app does successfully navigate to the expected address - `/detail/59b1dd167bd6d20e18cf795e` however it does not retrieve the expected results from that page, giving only a CastError. It strikes me that that may be because at some point it is routing to /detail/:_id rather than /api/clients/:_id. I will look into it more by the end of the week!